# Solution Verification: Implicit function and finding derivative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, implicit-function-theorem

Here's the question:

> Given the equation $z^3-xz-y=0$. 
> Prove that the equation defines an implicit function $z(x,y)$ in a neighborhood of point $(1,0,-1)$. 
> Calculate $\frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial x \partial y}$ in point $(1,0)$

**Solution**: 
I defined $F(x,y,z)=z^3-xz-y$ 
We have that $F(1,0,-1)=0$ 
The function $F$ is differentiable and it's partial derivatives are differentiable (polynomial). 
$F'_z(1,0,-1)=3(-1)^2-1=2\ne 0$ 
And thus, there exists a function $z(x,y)$ in a neighborhood of $(1,0,-1)$. 
And we know that: 
$Z'_y=- \frac{F'y}{F'z}=- \frac{-1}{3z^2-x}=\frac{1}{3z^2-x}$ 
And so $\frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial x \partial y}(1,0,-1)=\frac{1}{(3z^2-x)^2}=\frac{1}{(3(-1)^2-1)^2}=\frac{1}{4}$ 
I am mostly suspicious of my last calculation of the derivative, I am not sure of why I did the point $(1,0,-1)$, I would love to know why is it correct or false and any general feedback about my solution. 
Thanks in advance. 
**Fixing derivative with help of Joe:**
$\frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{-(6z*(\frac{-z}{3z^2-x})-1)}{(3z^2-x)^2}=\frac{1+\frac{6z^2}{3z^2-x}}{(3z^2-x)^2}$
And in $(1,0,-1)$---> $=1$

Comment: You had $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} =\frac{1}{3z^2-x}$, but then when you took $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{1}{3z^2-x}\right)$, it looks like you didn't use the chain rule. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Joe What I did was $\frac{f'g - fg'}{g^2}$ which is $\frac{0 - (-1)}{(3z^2-x)^2}$

Comment: It seems to me like you are forgetting to use the chain rule, or are you saying that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(3z^2-x\right)$ simplies to $-1$?

Comment: @Joe Yes that's exactly what I did

Comment: Since we are taking $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(3z^2-x)=6z \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} -1$. I didn't do the calculation, but are you saying that $6z \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} =0$?

Comment: @Joe Oh wow I completely missed that $z(x,y)$ should be differentiated, even though my professor had said it multiple times and warned us, guess I'll never forget it again now :), Thanks alot I'll fix it now

Comment: @Joe I fixed it, thanks alot for your help, would appreciate an approval, and if I could ask about the point $(1,0,-1)$, why are they asking for $(1,0)$? what's the logic behind it and how should I find out that they meant $(1,0,-1)$ and not something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same answer as you, except that I have:

$F_x = -z$

$F_z = 3z^2 - x$

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{F_x}{F_z} = \frac{z}{3z^2-x}$

So for the final answer I get:
$\frac{-(6z*(\frac{z}{3z^2-x})-1)}{(3z^2-x)^2}=\frac{1-\frac{6z^2}{3z^2-x}}{(3z^2-x)^2} = \frac{1-3}{4}= \frac{-1}{2}$

The reason that they asked for the partial derivative at $(1,0)$, instead of at $(1,0,-1)$, is because they were asking for the partial derivative of the function $z(x,y)$. However, you can still substitute $-1$ in for $z$ in the final answer, since you know that $z(1,0)=-1$.